# Telescope size to detect Ceres (Newtonian)

Tags: telescope

What is the minimum size telescope required to enable clear visual detection of Ceres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ceres varies between mag 9.3 and mag 6.7 which are below the nominal naked eye limiting magnitude of ~5. The [gain in limiting magnitude](http://w1.411.telia.com/~u41105032/visual/limiting.htm) for something like 10x50 binoculars (~4.5 magnitudes) would bring Ceres even at its faintest above the limiting magnitude of about 9.5.

Comment: Can't up-vote yet, but thanks, I can have a go with the binoculars without having to upgrade to anything serious.